# Firebase authWithPassword logout

Tags: firebase

Using Firebase's email / password login for my app and can't seem to find out how to logout an authenticated user after authWithPassword

Firebase's docs don't appear to have any explicit info on this

Anyone know how? I imagine I'm missing something silly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`ref.unauth()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/unauth.html) method (assuming you're using the JavaScript SDK)